# I want to extract coordinate data from NetLogo using the RNetLogo package

Tags: r, coordinates, netlogo

I'm using the sample Flocking code as an example to play with if anyone is familiar

```
NLCommand("set population 1")
NLCommand("setup")
nruns <- 10
timedata <- list()
for(i in 1:nruns) {
NLCommand("go")
timedata[[i]] <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who","xcor","ycor"),"turtles",
as.data.frame=T,df.col.names=c("who","xcor","ycor")) }
timedata
```

The problem is that it produces new headers for each model iteration. So I get the following instead of the header appearing only once:

```
[[1]]
 who     xcor      ycor
1   0 34.56833 -26.47777

[[2]]
 who     xcor      ycor
1   0 35.19765 -25.70063
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You may need to ask at http://groups.yahoo.com/group/netlogo-users/ . General NetLogo questions usually get good answers here at Stack Overflow, but it may be that the intersection of the sets of RNetLogo users and SO users is empty.

Comment: how about trying `do.call(rbind,timedata)` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's good discussion and answers on this at http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/conversations/topics/15551 (where OP asked the same question). Jan Thiele, author of the R extension for NetLogo, writes:

> If you really want to have all turtle coordinates in R, the more appropriate function is NLGetAgentSet and executing this in a loop over the ticks.
>   I have written a tutorial which comes with the RNetLogo package (see your RNetLogo installation directory). There is an example in chapter 11.5 (Time sliding visualization), where a similar thing is done. Adapting it to the Flocking model it could look like this: [...]

Comment: I think a response that is just a link should be a comment rather than a question ...

Comment: Not sure what the SO etiquette on that is — I didn't want the question to continue showing up as “unanswered”.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers; http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Thanks Ben. I added some more context and a quote.